# Access JavaScript Outside 'this' from Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, signalr

I don't even know how to word my question, and before I completely mess it up, here is my code:

```
className.prototype.requestData = function (start, end) {
    client.server.functionName(parameters)
        .done(function (msg) {
            if (msg) {                
                this.process(msg); //this belongs to client, not className as I want
            }
        })
        .fail(function (error) {
            console.log('failed: ' + error);
        });
}
```

As you can see, I need to call`process` to act on the data that is returned, and I don't want to use the variable I defined for it, I want to use `this`, and I'm guessing that isn't possible, is there a better to accomplish my goal?

Thanks

Comment: Is ES6 available? It would make this *very* straightforward.

Comment: @Thebluefish yes of course, please elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working in ES6, you can use async/await:

```
className.prototype.requestData = async function (start, end) {
    try {
        let result = await client.server.functionName(parameters);
        if (result ) {                
            this.process(result);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('failed: ' + err);
    }
}
```

If you wanted to "chain" them, you could do:

```
try {
    let result = await client.server.functionName(parameters);
    if (result) {                
        this.process(result);
    }
    // You can just call each in succession
    let other_result = await client.server.someOtherAsyncFunc(other_params);
    if(other_result) {
        // Do more stuff
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log('failed: ' + err);
}

// You can still call more promise-based functions after the try-catch block
let some_result = await client.server.yetAnotherAsyncFunc(more_params);
// Do other stuff with some_result
```

Comment: I like this approach, but is it possible to chain them together?  I like how I can that with Arrow function.  I have some calls that I need to wait on other calls

Comment: @Chris see my edit. Async/Await makes chaining promises *very* straight-forward.

Comment: I like Arrow Functions but this is much cleaner, and frankly the future, it is the answer I was looking for. thanks.

Comment: I like arrow functions, too. They have their place, and certainly used widely throughout my own projects.

Answer (score 2):

one way to do this is storing `this` in a variable and access it later :

```
className.prototype.requestData = function (start, end) {
    var _this = this;
    client.server.functionName(parameters)
        .done(function (msg) {
            if (msg) {                
                _this.process(msg); //this belongs to className as you want
            }
        })
        .fail(function (error) {
            console.log('failed: ' + error);
        });
}
```

using `bind` :

```
className.prototype.requestData = function (start, end) {
    client.server.functionName(parameters)
        .done(function (msg) {
            if (msg) {                
                this.process(msg); //this belongs to className as you want
            }
        }.bind(this))
        .fail(function (error) {
            console.log('failed: ' + error);
        });
}
```

otherwise, use arrow functions ( mentionned in other answers ) but the first one would be your best bet if you need to access both `this`es, more details and examples  : https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-es6-the-dope-way-part-ii-arrow-functions-and-the-this-keyword-381ac7a32881

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're in an environment that supports them (basically anything not IE at this point) you can use [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). From the link:

> An arrow function does not newly define its own this when it's being executed in the global context; instead, the this value of the enclosing lexical context is used, equivalent to treating this as closure value.

```
className.prototype.requestData = function (start, end) {
    client.server.functionName(parameters)
        .done((msg) => {
            if (msg) {                
                this.process(msg); //this belongs to client, not className as I want
            }
        })
        .fail((error) => {
            console.log('failed: ' + error);
        });
}
```

Without arrow functions, you'll have to store it in a closure variable. It just isn't possible otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
className.prototype.requestData = function (start, end) {
  var thisClassName = this;

  client.server.functionName(parameters)
    .done(function (msg) {
      if (msg) {
        thisClassName.process(msg);
      }
    })
    .fail(function (error) {
      console.log('failed: ' + error);
    });
}

// or in ES6 use arrow-function:

className.prototype.requestData = function (start, end) {
  client.server.functionName(parameters)
    .done((msg) => {
      if (msg) {
        // this is the instance of className.
        this.process(msg);
      }
    })
    .fail((error) => {
      console.log('failed: ' + error);
    });
}
```